# Activating Spring Profiles other than "cloud" in CloudFoundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I understand that on CloudFoundry allows the use of the cloud profile, however is it possible to activate more than one profile?  Along those lines, is it possible to specify the profile being activated beyond the cloud profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES. Cloud Foundry implicitly accepts profile named "cloud" but you can always activate whatever profile(s) your app ought to use. There are multiple ways to do that, among which I would prefer using the vmc client to set the system property:

```
vmc set-env APP JAVA_OPTS "-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud,cloud2"
```

For more details about the bean definition profile concept and usage, refer to the document here: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Comment: Since this answer was written, the Java buildpack for Cloud Foundry has been replaced with a newly designed Java buildpack. At the time of writing, it does not support the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, so the above technique will not work. Please refer to the [Java buildpack documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_opts.md#configuration) for how to set Java options.